# Does a weak limit inherit the asymptotic bound of the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be an open, connected, bounded domain with smooth boundary.

Let $g_n$ be measurable functions on $\Omega$, and suppose that $g_n \rightharpoonup g$ converges weakly in $L^1(K)$ for every compact subset $K \subseteq \Omega$.

Furthermore, suppose that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}m(\{x\,|\,g_n(x) \le 0)\}) = 0.$$

Is it true that $g \ge 0$ a.e. on $\Omega$?

---

**I think that I can prove this when the $g_n \ge r$ are uniformly bounded from below:**

Denote $A_n=\{x\,|\,g_n(x) \le 0\}$, and let $K \subseteq \Omega$ be compact. Then

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_K g_n=\int_K g.$$

Since $g_n \le 0 $ on $A_n$, we have

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_K g_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{K\cap A_n} g_n+\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{K\cap A_n^c} g_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{K\cap A_n^c} g_n \ge 0,$$

where we have used the fact that $rm(A_n) \le \int_{K\cap A_n} g_n \le  0$,
so $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{K\cap A_n} g_n=0$.

Thus
$$\int_K g \ge 0$$
for every compact $K$, so $g \ge 0$ a.e. on $\Omega$.

Comment: Just an idea, not too sure whether it works: $\min\{g_n, 0\} \to 0$ pointwise a.e. and $\min\{g_n, 0\} \to \min\{g, 0\}$ weakly in $L^1(K)$ for all compact $K$, hence $0 = \min\{g, 0\}$ a.e.